# Can not import Data.Stream in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, haskell-stack

Why can't I import Data.Stream in Haskell?

```
Prelude> import Data.Stream

<no location info>: error:
    Could not find module ‘Data.Stream’
    Perhaps you meant Data.String (from base-4.12.0.0)
```

Comment: Because you don't have the `stream-fusion` library installed?

Comment: Please do not post images that have important text on them. You should paste your error message directly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The module Data.Stream is not part of the standard library. You need to install a package that provides it first, probably using [Cabal](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/) or [Stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/).